# Read each character from file and store in array

Tags: scanf, verilog, system-verilog, fgets

I need to use Verilog to store each character from input file into an array.

I'm able to use `$fgets` to read each line, but I'm not sure how to break it down to each character.

Input file:

```
foo
bar 
joe
stack
```

main:

```
c = $fgetc(infile);
while(c != `EOF) begin
  r = ungetc(c,infile);
  $fgets(str,infile);
  c = $fgetc(infile);
  $display (%0s,str);
end
```

I want to store it into `str` so that `[0]str[0] = f` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$fscanf` to read one line at a time, discarding the newline character.  Since each line only has one word, store the word into a temporary string variable `word`.  Then push each word into a queue of strings.

```
module tb;

int fd;
string word;
string str [$];

initial begin
    fd = $fopen("data.txt", "r");

    while (! $feof(fd)) begin
        void'($fscanf(fd, "%s\n", word));
        str.push_back(word);
    end

    $display("%s", str[0][0]);
    $display("%s", str[0][1]);
    $display("%s", str[0][2]);
end

endmodule
```

Prints:

```
f
o
o
```

Comment: What is the use of void with $fscanf? I tried $fscanf without void and got the same result

Comment: fscanf() is a function which returns a value.  The way it is called here, no return value is accepted, therefore the tools will produce a warning; something like 'function called as task'. Using void() tells the tool there is no return value by design, and suppresses the warning.